# Call Macro(i) (For loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to find anything on the web for this. I am wondering if there is a way to call a **loop** of macro's. I have **Macro1() - Macro16()** and I want to run them consecutively based on the value in another cell. Using this code causes a compile error:

> Sub or Function not defined.

Can this be achieved?

```
Sub PlotAll()
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Sheet1.Range("T66") <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("T66") ' T66 is number of Macro's to perform
            Call Macroi
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "You do not have any points to plot.", vbExclamation
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful?

```
Sub dural()
    For i = 1 To 3
        Application.Run "Macro" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not, I even tried messing around with the similar post that was given to me. I get a type mismatch on `For i = 1 To ("T66")`

Comment: @KevinP.  Is the name of the first macro **T1** or **Macro1** or **MacroT1** ???

Comment: Nevermind. I needed to clarify where my range was by putting `Sheet1.Range("T66")` Thank you!

Comment: @KevinP.  Update this post if you require more help.